# Нужна ли запятая перед "или"? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или

Нужна ли запятая перед *или* (в первом случае) в следующем предложении: ***Как вы думаете, мы переживаем сейчас самые тяжелые времена, или они позади, или еще впереди?*** Чем обоснована постановка (отсутствие) этой запятой?

Answer (score 2):

**Как вы думаете, мы переживаем сейчас самые тяжелые времена, или они позади, или (они) еще впереди?**

Запятые ставятся между однородными придаточными, если **союз ИЛИ повторяется хотя бы один раз.** Интонация перечислительная.

Запятая не ставится, если союз ИЛИ одиночный: **Как вы думаете, мы переживаем сейчас самые тяжелые времена или они позади?**